# Controller unit test issue with constructing URL

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

One of my API Controller method routes is `"api/Students/GetList"`. It accepts two parameters: `'studentKey'` and `'isSenior'`

If I call this method from my unit test as follows then it works fine:

```
Get("api/Students/GetList/Super/false")
```

But if I call as following it does not go to the method's break point and complains about "method not found":

```
Get("api/Students/GetList/?studentKey=Super&isSenior=false");
```

Why? What's wrong with my second URL?

My `Controller method` looks like as follow

```
[Route("GetList/{studentKey}/{isSenior}")]
public IEnumerable<StudentSummary> Get(string studentKey, bool isSenior)
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: How does your controller method look like?

Comment: @ greenhoorn, updated my question with Controller method.

Comment: `Route` is an attribute, you need a server to parse your `URI` into the parameters. My guess is: You have 2 `GET` methods, so you test the wrong method.

Comment: @OldFox I have only one method in my controller with route "api/Students/GetList" ... not sure about your comments.

Comment: Ok, what is the meaning of `Server` in the `Get` lines. Please add your `UT` and the implementation of your `Get` method.

Comment: Ok, i have removed that 'Server' stuff which has nothing to do with URL format. Hence, i am ended at same problem mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined the `route` attribute on top of your `Get`-method, the controller is looking for the URL exactly like you specified.

```
[Route("GetList/{studentKey}/{isSenior}")]
```

The URL `"api/Students/GetList/Super/false"` matches because you are looking in the controller `Students` for the method `GetList`. Further the `GetList` method needs 2 parameters separated with a `/`. That's what you specify in your attribute.

The thing is, your second URL `"api/Students/GetList/?studentKey=Super&isSenior=false"` does not match these constraints and therefore the method can not be found.

---

To avoid these kind of problems I suggest you to overthink your architecture.

If I am right you get a list of all students and then filter with these attributes. That's not how it should work. Basically you should address **all** resources (like you do in `GetList`) or a **unique** one (like `GetList/studentXY`).